# Linux not answered to the point yet

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

```
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
```

Where does this `struct file*` point to? If we give a pointer variable of our own to `struct file*` and `struct inode*`. where is it pointing to? What is going on? I find the declarations in file operations struct.and definition of the same in driver program. But in driver program the pointer for `struct file *` and `struct inode*` comes out of nowhere? From where did u get those argument variables? Or can we give variable whatever we like? 
If it’s the otherwise , how does that random variable we give serve the purpose. 
I think the guy who first raised the question needs an answer for the same. 
Rather than making it complex can someone explain in simple if you know?

Comment: **Too many questions** in the single post. And the title is meaningless.

Comment: Ya that  was the answer to the question. Brilliant.Thank you for the comments

Answer (score 1):

[`read()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [`open()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) are userspace functions which operate on file descriptors. When a user runs an application which uses these functions, the kernel translates their call and populates the necessary information for the driver which instantiated the file. The kernel sort of "redirects" the userspace call and calls the driver `read()` and `open()` with the proper parameters filled in.

I'd recommend reading about driver file operations in [LDD3, Chapter 3](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf).

Comment: Ya I understood that brother. Those arguments is what is confusing. Like the file and node pointer variables which we have given while writing the driver module for that particular file inside kernel space. Actually how does it point to that particular node we need. We haven’t assigned an address to it right?

Comment: I have been reading those pdfs but still don’t get the point/ idea behind it, which forced me to raise the question. Can you help me out?